# Реализация админки интернет-магазина

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Я начинающий программист и меня мучает один вопрос, на который я не могу найти ответ. Я хочу себе написать интернет-магазин на php, все вроде нормально, только вот я не могу реализовать админку, чтобы можно было добавлять товары и они отображались на странице. Помогите или подскажите, плиз, что делать? С чего начать?

Comment: Начните с хороших книг в стиле **how to do**, например, для вашего случая, идеально подошла-бы книга "Робин Никсон - Создаем динамические веб-сайты с помощью PHP, MySQL и JavaScript
". Професионализму она не учит, но вам это и не надо, пока во всяком случае.

Answer (score 1):

Для начало нужно организовать базу данных. Структуру таблиц, связку между ними. Прикинуть нагрузку и распределить.

Для интернет магазина нужны как минимум следующие таблицы:

1. Таблица товаров.
2. Таблица категорий.
3. Таблица заказов.
4. Таблица фильтров товаров (по брендам, по спецификации - по сути это и есть метки)

На основе этих таблиц уже нужно писать интерфейс, что админку, что сам сайт.
Отделите php-код от html-кода. Сдейлает простой вывод на сайте и простые формы редактирования товаров в админке. Дальнейшее действие само нарисуется. Вам захочет одно, другое и т.д. и будете восполнять.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно хорошо знать php, html, css, javascript. А так вы магазин не сделаете. Посмотрите на готовые движки.

Comment: html знаю и php тоже и jquery немного, но я не знаю как мне это воплотить